# Git cannot commit curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.224.36.82 port 7107: Connection refused

Tags: git

I'm on the verge of a breakdown. I've been searching for hours and still haven't found the problem. I even reinstalled Git, but I keep getting this strange error. Whenever I try to commit in Git, it tries to connect to another Node project using a specific port number. This means I have to start the other project every time I want to commit, or else it will result in a timeout error. The address for the other project is 10.224.36.82:7107.

The error message is as follows:

```
\`\> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.224.36.82 port 7107: Connection refused\`
```

I have checked the hosts file and Git config proxy settings, and they are correct.

Comment: _" I have to start the other project"_ what does this means? Can you explain with an example?

Comment: There is something going on in a commit hook that you have setup so it's not really git the problem here... either fix the networking problem or disable the commit hook so that you can commit fine.

Comment: @eftshift0 Thank you very much, you're truly amazing! You quickly found the issue for me. I did find the relevant code in the git hooks. In the prepare-commit-msg file of Git, I indeed found the connection to a fixed IP. However, I'm not sure how this file came about. Thank you so much for saving me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. It was caused by the prepare-commit-msg file in Git hooks. Thank you again, @eftshift0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).